# How to disable multiple push Notification icon in Android, Am using Parse.com

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging

com push notification for Android app, All is working well but lets say if i send 5 push notification a day, i dont want user to see 5 notification icons at once on his phone. Its best if he sees only one.So is their any way where old notification is deleted and only latest is shown.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

The method that displays the notification has an int parameter which represents the notification identifier. If you use a constant identifier, each new notification will replace the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the notification ID to be the same value. So then they get replaced as each one arrives.

Comment: any help on how to set notification ID same.

Comment: you have to show the code on how are you showing the notification. It's probably something very similar to what @Eran replied.

Comment: Just pick a number and stick with it? The only problem with the notification Id being constant is that it will override existing notifications so you must be sure it's indeed what you want (for the old ones to be dismissed).

Answer (score 0):

int notificationId = 1 ;

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

```
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gcm_logo);
    builder.setContentTitle("Test Title");
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build());
```

So you can maintain notification Id for different type of notifications. If you keep same notification ID for each notification then it would be updated in the same .

If you have any extras in the pending intent and you want to update those extras with the latest ones then generate pending intent with :

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(), 
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);